# Find all $m$ such that there exists $P,Q,R$ satisfying polynomial conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials

**Problem**
Find all positive integer $m$ such that there exists $P(x), Q(x), R(x,y) \in \mathbb{R[x], R[x,y]}$ and for all $a^m=b^2$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we always have:

\begin{cases}
P(R(a,b))=a\\
Q(R(a,b))=b\\
\end{cases}.

**My attempts**

My first try was to bound the degree of the polynomials according to $m$ but that didn't yield much results. I was thinking about the number of roots, as $a$ definitely appear in the given equalities, but that was also stuck.

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you find such polynomials for $ m = 1, m  = 2$? Why, or why not?